# Cannot resolve symbol ExternalServiceResource while registering http client to jersey environment in Dropwizard Application

Tags: jersey, httpclient, dropwizard, jersey-client

Iam implementing Dropwizard client in a Dropwizard REST Application.
I am following their [User Manual](http://www.dropwizard.io/manual/client.html).

While trying to register the client to jersey environment but cannot find the class ExternalServiceResource

```
@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration config,
            Environment environment) {
final HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClientBuilder(environment).using(config.getHttpClientConfiguration())
                                                                .build();
environment.jersey().register(new ExternalServiceResource(httpClient));
}
```

Comment: can anyone let me know what to import so that i can resolve the missing class

Answer (score 6):

I think that ExternalServiceResource was an example but it would look like:

```
@Path("/your/path")
public class ExternalServiceResource {

    private final HttpClient client;

    public ExternalServiceResource(HttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @GET
    public String doStuff() {
        return /* use client to make some call */;
    }
}
```

You can put whatever name you want. The only requirement to create a resource is the @Path annotation, that you must put at class level, and some methods @GET, @POST...

Comment: i tried without the ExternalServiceResource and directly added the httpClient as a parameter to register function and it worked